# Comparing like elements in arrays and echoing out rest of the arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have created multiple arrays from text documents that are uploaded monthly.  One of the Arrays item numbers, description and picture.  the other array is item numbers, price and quantity.
What I am trying to do is if the item number is the same then be able to Echo out all the information that I need. Example would be

```
if($array1[0] ==$ array2[4]){
     echo $array1{4];
     echo $array2[6];
}
```

this doesn't work and having issues with getting array_intersect to work with it also.

Comment: So where do `item numbers, description and picture` and `item numbers, price and quantity` come into this? Don't you use meaningful variable names, or or do you believe in complete abstraction so your sample code bears no resemblance to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how there are so many variable inside an array. Item's number, description, and picture inside an array? I assuming you are looking for matching item's number inside both arrays so..
Good luck trying:

```
foreach($array1 as $a){
 foreach($array2 as $b){
  if($a==$b){
     echo $a;
  }
 }
}
```

Let me know how it works for you soon.

Answer (score 0):

this didnt work for what I was trying to do but I did figure it out.  I needed to use strpos() in a if statement to get the items I was looking for.